# How old an account is with php, unix timestamp

Tags: php-5.3, unix-timestamp

I am trying to make my accounts say how old they are in days... this is how I figured I would do it...

I would create a unix timestamp from when they joined, compare it to a unix timestamp when they access member pages, minus the original timestamp from the current one. This should give me how long their account has been 'alive' for in seconds.

In theory if I then divide by 60, and then 24, I should get the amount of days the account has been open, but it isn't working... here is my code...

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_GET['username']));
$view_user = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$seconds = time() - $view_user['joined'];
$days_old = ($seconds / 60) / 24;
```

Is there a better way of doing this, and where am I going wrong??

Comment: The magic number every programmer knows: 86400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$days_old = $seconds / 60 **/ 60** / 24;

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting 60 seconds per minute, 60 minutes per hour. You need to divide by 60 twice, ie. divide by 3600 (3600 = 60*60)

```
$days_old = ($seconds / 3600) / 24;
```

Comment: An easy mistake. :) I've made it myself enough times to have it committed to memory!